# Remove space after flalign* environment

Tags: flalign

I'm struggling to get rid of the indent after flalign* environments in an article document. This is an example of what I am speaking about:

```
Lewis's approach also results in the following consequences:
{\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
{\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\begin{flalign*}
    \textit{P(HEADS) } &= \textit{P(TAILS) } = \frac{1}{2} &\\
    \therefore P(H_1) &= \frac{1}{2} = P(T_1) + P(T_2) &\\
    \therefore P(T_1) &= P(T_2) = \frac{1}{4} &\\
    \therefore \frac{P(H_1)}{P(H_1) + P(T_1)} &= \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}} = \frac{2}{3} &\\
    \therefore P_+(HEADS) &= \frac{2}{3} = P(HEADS) + \frac{1}{6} &\\
    \therefore P_+(TAILS) &= \frac{1}{3}
\end{flalign*}}}
In other words, after Sleeping Beauty learns that it is Monday, and therefore is no longer
subject to any of the uncertainties associated with the experiment, her credence that a fair
coin will land on HEADS in an upcoming toss is $\frac{2}{3}$, despite the objective chance of it landing 
HEADS being $\frac{1}{2}$. This is completely nonsensical.
```

[image]
I would like to remove the indent before the text after the flalign* environment (the small space before the word "In"). I have tried using \noindent. I also have the following in my .sty file:

```
% No paragraph indenting
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is due to the end-line after the `}}}`.

You could add `%` to remove it, but there's a better way.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newenvironment{lewis}
 {%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{3pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{3pt}%
  \begin{equation*}
  \begin{minipage}{\displaywidth}
  $\begin{aligned}
 }
 {%
  \end{aligned}$%
  \end{minipage}%
  \end{equation*}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
 }

\begin{document}

Lewis's approach also results in the following consequences:
\begin{lewis}
    P(\mathit{HEADS}) &= P(\mathit{TAILS})  = \frac{1}{2} \\
    \therefore P(H_1) &= \frac{1}{2} = P(T_1) + P(T_2) \\
    \therefore P(T_1) &= P(T_2) = \frac{1}{4} \\
    \therefore \frac{P(H_1)}{P(H_1) + P(T_1)} &=
      \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}} = \frac{2}{3} \\
    \therefore P_+(\mathit{HEADS}) &= \frac{2}{3} = P(\mathit{HEADS}) + \frac{1}{6} \\
    \therefore P_+(\mathit{TAILS}) &= \frac{1}{3}
\end{lewis}
In other words, after Sleeping Beauty learns that it is Monday, and therefore is no longer
subject to any of the uncertainties associated with the experiment, her credence that a fair
coin will land on $\mathit{HEADS}$ in an upcoming toss is $\frac{2}{3}$, despite the objective 
chance of it landing $\mathit{HEADS}$ being $\frac{1}{2}$. This is completely nonsensical.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I changed a little the code, to make it consistent: you never want `\textit` for something which is not a parenthetical remark in a math environment. And if you use *HEADS* in the formula (in italics) it should be so also in the running text.

Using a specific environment means that if you want to modify it, for example adding the standard spacing above and below the display (I can't see a reason to remove it), you can just comment out the relevant lines and get

[image]

without chasing in the document for `\abovedisplayskip`.

Comment: Thanks, the % solution was exactly what I was looking for! Your example of defining a new environment is also great for people who are going to use multiple such environments throughout a paper. I happened to just have one flalign* that I needed to change in a larger paper. Also, thanks for the notes on consistency!

Comment: I was trying to avoid defining a new environment. Another solution that involves defining a new environment that may be useful for people with the same issue that I had can be seen here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101040/how-to-remove-unnecessary-space-after-flalign-environment