# adjust vertical space of equations in proof environment

Tags: equations, environments, environment-variables

Is there any way to change the variables `\abovedisplayskip` `\belowdisplayskip` etc. for the proof environment only?
I want the default spacing in theorems and definitions, but want to avoid my proofs exploding due to equations.
I use the `amsthm` package for the proof environment, the main spacing is set in `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]`

Comment: Short answer: "Yes". The likely usability of any longer answer will increase tremendously if you share some details about your document setup. E.g., do you use a package to create theorem-like environments, and how do you determine line-spacing in the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching I found
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101045/234434
and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1566053
Combining them I got the following which is exactly what I need.

```
\let\dummyproof\proof  
\def\proof{\dummyproof\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}}
```

Comment: `proof` is defined in `amsthm`, not in `amsmath`.  And have you tried to use this with `\qedhere`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton changed the package in the question, thx. As of the `\qedhere`, it doesn't mess with the redefined vertical space, if that's what you mean.

Comment: `\qedhere` doesn't have any effect on the vertical space, but some redefinitions of proof manage to obliterate `\qedhere`, and that's all I was referring to.

Comment: no, `\qedhere` works just fine